# Generating a timeline in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

I would like to insert a timeline at the top of my LilyPond score that shows every second. This could look something like this:

```
#(set-default-paper-size "a3landscape")
#(set-global-staff-size 18)

\paper { 
indent = #0 
ragged-right = ##f} 

#(define timeline '((snare default #f  3)))
    
    click = \drummode {  
    \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #(alist->hash-table timeline)
    { 
    sn8^\markup \center-align "00:00"  
    8^\markup \center-align "00:01"   
    8^\markup \center-align "00:02"  
    8^\markup \center-align "00:03"   
    \pageBreak 
    }
    }
    
    <<
    \new DrumStaff \with { 
      instrumentName = "Timeline"
      shortInstrumentName = "time" 
      \override StaffSymbol.line-count = #1
      \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-1 . 1)
      \omit Voice.BarLine
      \hide NoteHead 
      \hide Flag 
      \hide Beam 
      \omit Clef 
      \omit TimeSignature 
      \hide LedgerLineSpanner 
      \omit BarNumber 
    }
    { \click } 
    >>
```

Instead of inserting each second manually into the file (or using Python to generate the content of the "click" variable [see above], i.e. a long text file that I would then insert into LilyPond), I would like to generate a function that outputs ascending seconds (in the format mm:ss, where m stands for minute and s for second - 02:23 means: 2 minutes and 23 seconds) and places them above the notes.

So a function where I say, for example, "Start at minute 00:00 and go in one-second increments up to minute 10:00 and write the seconds above my note stems."

My Scheme knowledge is far too limited for me to be able to write something like that. But maybe someone here will be kind enough to help me out?

I would be extremely grateful for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
#(set-default-paper-size "a3landscape")
#(set-global-staff-size 18)

\paper { 
indent = #0 
ragged-right = ##f} 

#(define timeline '((snare default #f 3)))
    
clickrange =
#(define-music-function (from to step) (number? number? number?)
   #{
     $@(map (lambda (time)
              (let ((minutes (quotient time 60))
                    (seconds (remainder time 60)))
                #{ 
                  \drummode {
                    \scaleDurations #step {
                      sn8\tweak self-alignment-X #CENTER
                         ^\markup #(format #f "~2,'0d:~2,'0d" minutes seconds)
                    }
                  }
                #}))
            (iota (floor (/ (- to from) step)) from step))
   #})

\layout {
  \context {
    \DrumStaff
    \type Engraver_group
    \name TimeStaff
    \alias DrumStaff

    \override StaffSymbol.line-count = #1
    \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-1 . 1)
    \omit Voice.BarLine
    \hide NoteHead 
    \hide Flag 
    \hide Beam 
    \omit Clef 
    \omit TimeSignature 
    \hide LedgerLineSpanner 
    \omit BarNumber
    drumStyleTable = #(alist->hash-table timeline)
  }
  \context {
    \Score
    \accepts TimeStaff
  }
}

<<
  \new TimeStaff \with { 
    instrumentName = "Timeline"
    shortInstrumentName = "time" 
    \textLengthOn
  }
  { 
    \clickrange #0 #(* 2 60) #1
    \clickrange #(* 2 60) #(* 4 60) #2
  }
>>
```

It would also be possible to create a custom engraver for this. This has the advantage that Lilypond would be able to determine the actual time from Metronome markings.